# Stack Overflow often not available and returns error 404 or

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, 404-not-found

I am a Stack Overflow user from Italy. I often get this error when accessing Stack Overflow, particularly from Google searches

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Retrying some time later on and I get the site correctly.
More frequent with Chrome.

Some questions which gave me errors in the last few days:

- [AngularJS : Insert HTML into view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381926/insert-html-into-view-using-angularjs)
- [Converting a Stripes application to use Friendly URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725534/converting-a-stripes-application-to-use-friendly-urls)

Here you are the HAR of my request

```
{
  "log": {
    "version": "1.2",
    "creator": {
      "name": "WebInspector",
      "version": "537.36"
    },
    "pages": [
      {
        "startedDateTime": "2013-06-05T12:47:10.936Z",
        "id": "page_1",
        "title": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133981/best-way-to-use-welcome-file-in-web-application",
        "pageTimings": {
          "onContentLoad": 264,
          "onLoad": 336
        }
      }
    ],
    "entries": [
      {
        "startedDateTime": "2013-06-05T12:47:10.936Z",
        "time": 57,
        "request": {
          "method": "GET",
          "url": "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133981/best-way-to-use-welcome-file-in-web-application",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Pragma",
              "value": "no-cache"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Encoding",
              "value": "gzip,deflate,sdch"
            },
            {
              "name": "Host",
              "value": "stackoverflow.com"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept-Language",
              "value": "en-US,en;q=0.8"
            },
            {
              "name": "User-Agent",
              "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.93 Safari/537.36"
            },
            {
              "name": "Accept",
              "value": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
            },
            {
              "name": "Referer",
              "value": "https://www.google.it/"
            },
            {
              "name": "Cookie",
              "value": " REMOVED FOR PRIVACY"
            },
            {
              "name": "Connection",
              "value": "keep-alive"
            },
            {
              "name": "Cache-Control",
              "value": "no-cache"
            }
          ],
          "queryString": [],
          "cookies": [ REMOVED FOR PRIVACY ]
       ,
          "headersSize": 824,
          "bodySize": 0
        },
        "response": {
          "status": 404,
          "statusText": "Not Found",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "Date",
              "value": "Wed, 05 Jun 2013 12:47:10 GMT"
            },
            {
              "name": "Server",
              "value": "Apache"
            },
            {
              "name": "Connection",
              "value": "Keep-Alive"
            },
            {
              "name": "Keep-Alive",
              "value": "timeout=2, max=90"
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Length",
              "value": "263"
            },
            {
              "name": "Content-Type",
              "value": "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [],
          "content": {
            "size": 263,
            "mimeType": "text/html",
            "compression": 0
          },
          "redirectURL": "",
          "headersSize": 200,
          "bodySize": 263
        },
        "cache": {},
        "timings": {
          "blocked": 0,
          "dns": -1,
          "connect": 0,
          "send": 1,
          "wait": 53,
          "receive": 1,
          "ssl": -1
        },
        "pageref": "page_1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's coming from Stack Overflow server? Can you take screenshot of the whole error page next time it happens?

Comment: Google isn't redirecting your links?

Comment: Maybe a crappy corporate proxy?

Comment: Do not think so; the url in the address bar is the stackoverflow url, and if I hit reload it still gives me the error.

Comment: Maybe some security software you have that trying to protect you when detecting certain "malicious" contents in pages?

Comment: My laptop has ubuntu 13.04 with no security add-ons. We do not have a corporate proxy. Also a colleague of mine with ubuntu/chrome has the same problem.

Comment: Obviously, it's not global problem or else Meta was flooded with reports. Maybe your ISP is to blame, really can't know for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our tech staff finally verified that it was a DNS problem at our provider which erroneously resolved "stackoverflow.com" to a local ip.

Thanks for the prompt support!